# Initialize tuple with same parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I can't seem to wrap my ahead around this. Is there a way to initialize a tuple where each element takes the same parameter? For example...

```
template <class... args>
std::tuple<args...> tuplemaker(int n)
{
    // What goes here?
}

auto my_tuple = tuplemaker<int, int, int>(42);
```

A contrived example to be sure. What I'd really like to do is pass the same parameter repeatedly to the constructor of my tuple elements. Does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
template <class... args>
  std::tuple<args...> tuplemaker(int n)
{
  return std::make_tuple(args(n)...);
}
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/lVEZY6).

Comment: If you want implicit casts, write `template<typename T, typename U> T implicit_cast( U&& u ) { return std::forward<U>(u); }` and do `return std::make_tuple( implicit_cast<args>(n)... )` in your `tuplemaker` -- explicit function-style casts of one argument can end up doing `reinterpret_cast`, which can be overly aggressive... (have one of your `args` be a pointer, and you'll silently cast that `int` to a pointer.)

Comment: Well that was unexpectedly simple. Thank you!